# Unable to perform any kind of operation on MircoSD card

Tags: filesystems, gparted

I have a 8 GB SDcard that look like this in gparted:
[image: gparted]

My goal is to have a single 8 GB partition on the SDcard.

When I try to perform any operation (delete partition, create new partition, change format, etc) its successful but nothing changes.
[image: gparted delete all]

Gparted shows that all operations are successful:
[image: gparted all successful]

But when I click Close it will reload the device and show the same partition table as before.

I also ran "sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M" which showed no error but the partitions are still there.

One more strange thing is that if mount one of the partitions (eg sdb1) add or delete any files, eject/unmount and remount. The changes are gone (no files added or removed). The same thing happens when I access the 1GB FAT32 partition on a Windows PC.

Is there any way the SDcard could be locked to prevent all those changes?
Is there a way to solve this or do i need a new SDcard?

Comment: sorry the question, to clarify, did you unmount each partition before proceed to the deletion? thx

Comment: I feel you are not using the gparted options correctly. Read the gparted manual.

Comment: @lese: Nothing is mounted when I use gparted.

I've edited the initial question to include more information on what I do with gparted

Comment: Yes, a SDCard can be physically write-protected.

Comment: @Vinz: I assume you mean the little switch that is in most sd to mircosd adapters? - I don't use and adapter. I plug the micro sdcard directly into a reader.
Is there a different way on a micro sdcard I might be missing?

Comment: @Vinz: it is a hardware switch, but the write protection is implemented in software (e.g. the firmware running on the USB SD card reader). Cheap card readers might nog implement this, be warned! Don't depend on this to protect your data.

Comment: Try removing the SD card after performing the `dd` command, and reinsert again.

Comment: Hey @wurtel. Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that but sadly the result is the same.